# Bigcommerce api create product

Tags: bigcommerce

I have to import my products data in bigcommerce using csv file. Right now i am using create product api method but i have an issue of category while uploading product.

In csv file i have category data by name not by id. But in API parameter category should be pass by array of id. Is their any way that i use category by name in PHP script as parameter ?

```
<product>
<name>xbox</name>
<type>physical</type>
<description>this is a test item</description>
<price>499.99</price>
<categories>
<categories>DIAHATSU/ROCKY/F70/AXLE</categories>
</categories>
<availability>available</availability>
<weight>0.5</weight>
</product>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a method of

```
.GetOrInsertGetCategory(String name)
```

I supply a string, it either returns the existing integer value of the category (via a select service call to BigCommerce) or it inserts a new one (again, via the BigCommerce service) and returns the integer value.

I tried being cheap about the categories but it's fairly core to product insertion and if you don't get it right then you end up doing a ton of manual category organizing via the /admin/ interface, and that ain't no fun.